I seem to be in the cloudflare penalty box, is there anything I can do to get out?
For about the last week or so, when I visit a page on SO, and have not visited a page in the last minute or so, I get a note that cloudflare is verifying that I am a human.  Sometimes there is a captcha checkbox, sometimes not.  It also occurs if I visit other stackexchange sites.  In addition, I noted (around the same time) images in questions and answers no longer load with the page, and I get inline links which usually allow me to see those images if I click on them.
Reading other meta posts it seems to be almost exactly this.   I'm accessing this from a VDI machine in a US datacenter at my employer, and when I do ipchicken from that machine, and feed the reported IP into a public whois site, it indicates that the IP address is owned by my employer.
Its additionally "problematic" because if I try to make a comment after the penalty box timeout has elapsed, or I am editing a post and the penalty box timeout elapses, then I get a variety of errors from "nothing happens" to  a red error pop-up that the operation failed.
I do have 20 or so chrome browser tabs open, but only one of them points to a SE site.
If I switch to another machine (e.g. at home, using my home ISP), whether logged in to SO or not, the behavior appears to be normal - no cloudflare check, post images load automatically as expected.
Is there any way to further identify what is going on, why I am in this penalty box, or how to get out?

"a VDI machine in a US datacenter" - I'm gonna hazard a guess this is the culprit. A common DDOS attack vector these days is to spin up a bunch of workers in cloud provider infrastructure. My guess is Cloudflare has flagged IPs from that datacenter as problematic, so you're subject to additional scrutiny when hitting anything behind cloudflare.

I imagine anything is possible.  But the machine is not in the public cloud.  It's in a datacenter that is entirely owned and run by my employer, and has no other tenants besides my employer.  We still may have problematic traffic, of course.  I have no idea.  But I would discount the idea of an actual rogue bot network in this datacenter.  That is quite unlikely, IMO.

Probably doesn't matter who owns it if CF has flagged it as a datacenter. SE might've added a rule that adds much stricter restrictions for datacenters, for example. Pretty much all the user blocking as of late have been excessively strict blocks aimed specifically at genAI scrapers, with all legitimate applications (and legitimate end-users) being deprioritised. It's not possible to verify what rules are in place without an employee looking into it though (and even then, you rely on them actually wanting to and being able to comment, which is a whole other thing:tm:)

It seems like Cloudflare might be flagging your employer's datacenter IP due to how it sees traffic from that location, especially with a VDI setup. Even though it’s a private network, it might still trigger their DDoS protection. I’d suggest talking to your IT team to see if they can reach out to Cloudflare to whitelist your IP. In the meantime, using your home connection seems like a good workaround.

Likely the only solution, as SE is done "tuning" their config by now and doubt they'll touch it again. Naturally when over-protecting, there would be lots of false positives, this case is just one of them. I'm certain there are many others who just silently give up and go away.

@ShadowWizard No, they're not. They're still actively making CF and non-CF changes to block bots. As two examples, in the last few months (unclear when), search was capped to 500 results for anon users. Question pages, list pages, search, and 404 pages (to name a few) have gotten aggressive bot filtering within the last couple weeks via Cloudflare JavaScript detections (an anti-bot platform used in various other rules). That particular bot detection system was (according to the IA) rolled out on 2024-08-30, and happens to be responsible for killing the comment archive.

Because everything involved is closed-source, it's incredibly difficult to identify what, when, and how bad Some Thing:tm: is, especially because (AFAIK), none of these changes have been announced, but there are ongoing quiet changes being made. There's also a lot of parts involved, and without honest and open communication from SE, it isn't possible to tell what changed, if anything. I'm honestly surprised it took this long to affect end-users, or at least for an affected end-user to make a report.

Also fun, because Cloudflare itself is flaky, it's not possible to tell whether Cloudflare did something, or if SE did something, without an SE employee checking who introduced excessively aggressive filtering this time. I doubt contacting CF is going to help - they'll probably defer to SE instead. I imagine any whitelisting would have to be done on SE's end (though I strongly doubt SE would/can do it)

@Zoe ah sorry, I mean they don't make changes to fight false positives: they just go wild with CF protection, and stopped listening to feedbacks about it. This is all the proof I need - the developer who previously did it, is silent for over two months, while the bug reports about it keep piling up. :/
